# SSRS Row Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, row

SSRS Report. The Problem is I already have a very established report with tons of Expressions and Calculations.  I need to group the highlighted area into it's own row group. How can i do this after the fact?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create create the new group, add rows to it and then copy and paste everything down. If you have code that won't copy (e.g. custom code =code.function()), comment it out with ', copy, paste and then uncomment it.